# global.css is not responding to changes made to @media in Sapper app

Tags: svelte, sapper

I'm using sapper original template which includes the global.css file. In that file there is @media with the following setting:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
        body {
            font-size: 14px;

        }
    }
```

I just added the background-color : brown; and nothing happens. Isn't that file purpose is to apply the css in that file to every page in the app?
I'm aware of adding  : global() to the component style

```
:global(html) {
  background-color: green;
  }
```

But I need all changes to be in one place so the global.css should be updated to:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
        body {
            font-size: 14px;
            background-color: greenyellow; <!-- Added this -->
        }
    }
```

but nothing changes if I add the change to global.css file. Only when I add it to the component style. How to add that change to global.css and get it applied from global.css? How to get global.css to be the main provider of the css in my sapper app by adding the background-color in the global.css?

Comment: Hello, it's well working for me with a brand new install of sapper. I think you can check few things:

Comment: - reload your app (global.css is not live reloaded)
- is global.css link still present in your template.html file
- inspect global.css in your browser and look for your code

Another solution could be to put your code in the _layout.svelte file which is applied for all routes

Comment: @nlarche You're correct. I needed to restart the app. Working now. Thank you for your help. I'll upvote your answer.